# Why some of my vector layers do not display and some of them do?

Tags: qgis, layers

I was trying to re-add the water, building, and protected areas layer again but it does not work, It just displayed landuse area and roads, do you know why this could happen?

[image]

Comment: as with your previous question you have probably put a layer on top of them and can see through it.

Comment: It could be a projection issue (ie. you data are displayed but in the "wrong" place) to check that right click on your layer and choose zoom to layer ; Or it could be caused by geometry error preventing the layer to properly display try to run the check geometry tool on your layer. If nothing work then give more detail on your data and process...

Comment: For the building, note how it is greyed-out in the TOC, meaning it is scale dependent and not displayed at the current scale. Try zooming in.

Comment: Can you see the records in the layers attribute table? /  After checking what J.R wrote, try loading the layers with the default symbology. It could be an undesired layer or feature blending mode

Comment: It seems that there is no value in the layers attribute table, I also tried to download those layers again, but the attribute table still empty, do you know why it could happen??

Comment: J.R. I run the checked geometry tool for those layers and it appears that it marks in GEO instead of QGIS, as result, it displayed some layers such as error output or invalid output